# Are Golang goroutines (relatively) the same as C# tasks?

Tags: c#, performance, go, concurrency

I keep hearing how Go is the greatest thing since sliced bread for concurrency but so far I haven't seen much proof of that. In fact I haven't found any good synchronizing constructs besides wait groups and channels for synchronization.

Supposedly goroutines should be very lightweight and fast, since they are not an actual thread but an abstraction used by Go, that made me think of C#'s Tasks.

Does anyone know, from data or tests being run, not just word of mouth, if goroutines are faster/lighter than C# tasks?

I'm trying to find out if there's any reason or benefit to use Go if I already know C#.

Comment: Coroutines are analogous to `async` `await` in C#.  Treat them accordingly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, but async/await have nothing to do with threads. Await marshalls the call to a driver or to a `Task`. Before anyone tries to burn me at the skate: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Comment: The "Task" part of my previous comment refers to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Coroutines can run on a single thread or on multiple threads, just like `async` `await`.

Comment: And if you go [two articles down](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model) in the MSDN docs you linked, you'll see that async/await can be implemented using multiple threads, or as continuations on the same thread.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes that was what I was referring to about the tasks, it is also in the article I linked. In all cases, async/await does NOTHING about threads, in your article it is the TASKS that do all the thread work and async/await just waits on them. It literally is "wait for this task". Unless I am interpreting goroutines wrong, because AFAIK a goroutine handles work on whatever/however thread it feels like but it does not wait on another thread mechanism, like await does.

Comment: Well, I don't see a meaningful distinction there.  The effect is the same; it can be one thread or many, in both cases.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: The big difference is that C# tasks cannot be preempted. (Edit: The thread they are scheduled on can of course be preempted, but that is not the same thing.)

Answer (score 10):

There are significant differences between the behavior of Go goroutines and C# tasks that I would not consider them equivalent.

### Common Features

They are both userspace threading systems capable of doing M:N threading (large number of lightweight threads on top of a small number of OS threads).

### Differences

- Goroutines can be preempted. This means that no matter how many compute-bound goroutines you have, you can't block other work from progressing.
- Goroutines can hold locks across I/O. This is disallowed in C# tasks.
- You can control how C# tasks are scheduled, using a scheduler of your own choosing, freely assign different tasks to different pools of threads, or assign priorities to tasks. You can even run all your C# tasks on a single thread.
- Code that runs in a goroutine is just ordinary Go code. C# code must be rewritten to use async / await / Task.

The way I see it, C# tasks are syntactic sugar for rewriting your code as a state machine and capturing state as objects on the heap rather than on the stack. All scheduling is done in ordinary library code on top of an existing thread primitive.

Goroutines are designed to be much closer to OS threads in terms of their behavior (locks, IO, and preemption) although they are not perfect.

It is easy enough to make your C# tasks deadlock if you use ordinary threading primitives to wait for a condition, but the task scheduler has no remaining threads available to schedule the task you are waiting for. That's why you can't await while a lock is held, the scheduler might schedule a second task which ends up waiting for the lock held by the first task.

The big benefit of the C# way of doing things is that you can use your own scheduler. I used this extensively when unit testing. It can be a bit more annoying to write tests for concurrent Go code compared to how easy it is in C#.

Comment: All interesting observations.  How do they compare in terms of performance (which is what the OP asked)?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't consider that part of the question to be answerable, so I didn't answer it.

Comment: The last dot point doesn't make sense. `async/await/Tasks` are part of the C# programming language -  you would only need to re-write C# code to use `async/await` if you didn't bother to use them in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that’s exactly when you have to rewrite your C# code. I don’t see what’s nonsensical about that—you can write code in a synchronous, threaded style, or in an asynchronous style, and you need to rewrite it to change from one to the other.

Comment: Someone writing a simple, straightforward, single-threaded program may start out using synchronous APIs. This is entirely reasonable and there’s nothing wrong with that. It can be a lot of work to make the code asynchronous.